# How to uninstall

Tags: macos, uninstallation, cloud-foundry

Any idea how to uninstall Micro CloudFoundry? I am running on OSX.

I searched throughout the cloudfoundry sites and with google to no avail.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Micro Cloud Foundry is a virtual machine. To uninstall, you just have to delete the whole folder containing the `.vmx` file. You can also right click on the VM in Fusion and choose "delete". Of course, after doing that, you'll lose everything you deployed on Micro Cloud Foundry.